# How to separate Apostrophe syles from the front end template

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I keep running into the conflicts between the front end CSS styles and Apostrophe's own.
For example, after i added the template Apostrophe form input fields are now shown in all capitals and alignment is all off.
Is there a recommended way to separate them into different scopes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more specifics or, better yet, a github project where we can see the form that is having trouble? Our form styles are scoped to apos-ui and shouldn't be affecting your own forms. Unless you are actually using our form macros in which case you're opting into those styles, yes.

Comment: here's the prototype.  it's all static right now (separate templates for each page) since it's a typical small site project where the content is being created adhoc.  Once we finalize  page layout i'll convert editable areas into widgets to leverage Apostrophe.   
https://github.com/uncircled/dsm  
  
staged version is at http://www.destination-spa-management.com/
(admin / snow2water)  
I'm importing all theme styles in stie.less 
  
VadimG,  i suspect you're right and some of the theme styles are scoped globally will have to go through and reduce that scope.

Comment: The github URL is a 404 FYI.

Comment: sorry,  forgot it's a private repository.  if you send me your email i can add you.

Comment: tom@punkave.com

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common issue to CMSes, not only to Apostrophe. Personally, I've developed a habit of limiting the scope of all my CSS and JS files to that of the modules they refer to and since then I've never had any single issue with it.

I.e. I have a module called widget and I wrap it in an element that has class 'widget'. This allows me to scope my css only to that '.widget'. Luckily using [BEM](https://en.bem.info/) and less makes scoping a walk in the park.

Comment: This is generally the way the Apostrophe team develops client projects. Very little/nothing in the global scope and very tight scoping and containers around things like widgets & rich text (we use ITCSS so these are mostly objects and components)