# How-to style links without crashing Admin UI?

Tags: css, apostrophe-cms

I've problems related to [how-to-separate-apostrophe-syles-from-the-front-end-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313346/how-to-separate-apostrophe-syles-from-the-front-end-template).

How can I style `<a>`-tags without breaking the Admin UI? 
Do I have to give each `<a>` in my own widgets a style-class `<a class="mystyle">`?

**What's the way to style the links of the provided richtext-widget?**

Do I have to use `.apos-rich-text a` to stop changing the admin-control ui of the widget?

Because the following breaks the Admin UI.

```
.custom-main-container a:hover {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

The menus texts become white on hover and can't be read.

**What's the way to handle the styling and to be sure you don't oversee anything?!**

Comment: i don't understand what is problem with using `.apos-rich-text a` for overriding css

Comment: It's just an example. I would have to fiddle out where I have to set my a-style elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The Apostrophe dev team typically stays away from styling at the element level for exactly this reason, however CKEditor doesn't allow you to apply classes on links easily.

An easy and tight way to scope styles to the `a` element and not interfere with Apostrophe's admin UI is to add a project level class to the rich text widget wrapper.

In your project level `/lib/modules/apostrophe-rich-text-widgets/views/widget.html`

```
<div data-rich-text class="apos-rich-text MY-RICH-TEXT">{{ data.widget.content | safe }}</div>
```

Then in your CSS you can write

```
.MY-RICH-TEXT a:hover { //whatever }
```

Be sure to leave `data-rich-text` in the wrapper, Apostrophe is using that attribute to enhance the widget on the front-end.

Comment: And I have to do similiar for all other widgets?

Comment: It is somehow a mess. What's about layout widgets? How should you style the layout without breaking apos-ui? Doesn't miss apostrophe to set some important styles on their class names? Isn't this a bug?

Comment: Each widget needs a template, which is your opportunity to give the wrappers project-level class names .. that is what we typically do. We make it a house practice to not scope to any `apos-*` classes.

Comment: If you think there is an actual bug it would be helpful to write up a quick summary about what you're trying to accomplish, code samples for trying to accomplish it, and what you think is broken

Answer (score 0):

My shame... the problem is the `!important` above.
This makes the specificity too high. Somehow I didn't get this too my mind before.

Although it would be great if the admin UI would get more specificity so that it is not so easy to overwrite its rules by 2 class-selectors.